# Query for selecting a record and insert 3 replica records of it with increment in sequence number column by Max +1 for each three records

Tags: sql, db2

need to replicate 1 row in 3 new rows with incremented sequence number +1 in each new row

```
insert into t1 (column1,column2,column3,sequencecolumn)
(  **row1
select *from t1 (column1,'101',column3,sequencecolumn)
(select max (sequencecolumn)+1 where column1 ='abc')
where column1 = 'abc'
)  
(   ***row2
select *from t1 (column1,'102',column3,sequencecolumn)
(select max (sequencecolumn)+1 where column1 ='abc')
where column1 = 'abc'
)
(  ***row3
select *from t1 (column1,'103',column3,sequencecolumn)
(select max (sequencecolumn)+1 where column1 ='abc')
where column1 = 'abc'
)
```

Comment: i need to select rows where column1 = abc and column2 = 100
abc, 100, seq1 ................row1 .......................
abc,100, seq2  ...............row2 ........................
abc 099, seq3 ................row3 ........................
now if i need max seq number of 'abc'  .ie. seq3
but i need to only fetch records having 'abc' and '100'
and replicate it but count sequence should be seq4
primary key is 'abc' +seqnumber column .. not the column 2 having value 100

what to do in such a case

Answer (score 1):

I might try something like this (if I had a DB2 installation handy):

```
INSERT INTO t1 (
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  sequencecolumn
)
SELECT
  t.column1,
  v.column2,
  t.column3,
  MAX(t.sequencecolumn) + v.rn
FROM t1 t
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1, '101'), (2, '102'), (3, '103')) v (rn, column2)
GROUP BY
  t.column1,
  t.column3,
  v.column2,
  v.rn
WHERE t.column1 = 'abc'
;
```

Comment: `v.rn` is one of the two columns in the `v` inline table (the one defined with the VALUES clause). The other is `column2` (which you might want to name differently, I only picked that name to match the `column2` in `t1`)